# Insert variable in php databse query

Tags: php, mysql

This is pretty simple but I can't seem to find the answer i'm looking for.

This works perfectly :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('MyValue')");
```

But this does not work :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('" + $_POST['course'] + "')");
```

I tested and I know that `$_POST['course']` contains `MyValue`.
Am I even allowed to use this syntax in php ?

Sql Injection is not a concern in my case.

Comment: use '.' not '+'  its php not javascript

Comment: Mysql_* is deprecated. And this is prone to SQL injection...

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('".$_POST['course']."')");`

Comment: If you're only just learning about PHP and MySQL databases, learn the MySQLi or PDO libraries with prepared statements rather than the deprecated MySQL library - learn the correct way of doing it from the start

Comment: i'm sorry i've never done any web programming and i'm used to .Net Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Wiggler that's vulnerable to  SQL injection

Comment: what is the '+' doing there?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I know, but then I would need to tell him all 999 things he would get by reading :] also mysql_* is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` instead of `+`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']) . "')");
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @Pekka웃 you are right but I just want to clear that use `.` instead of `+`

Comment: The SQL injection is not at all a concern in my case. I know about it and it's in no point related to the question.

Comment: @Pha it's still not good practice to show vulnerable code. People learn from SO answers (I edited it in)

Comment: If you knew about it, you'd **escape your strings**.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses . to concatenate strings

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course'])."')");
```

Also use mysql_real_escape_string to prevent any errors, like o'neil having a single quote in it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use mysqli, not mysql , because it is deprecated.

2) Always escape the variables coming from your site, with mysql_real_escape string, if you STILL use mysql...

3) debug your code. The fastest in your example simply use:

```
      mysql_query("... your sql string ") or die(mysql_error())
```

Than you see the error. (but when your script go live, comment out all "or die(mysql_error())+ code, so the others could not see the errors , and hack your site (so easy) )

4) . is the concatenation of the strings in php, not +

Comment: you are right, i corrected the point 2.
I wrote that, because i observed that only a few php programmer want to replace mysql, to mysqli... and less than less wants to use objectum orientated code.. or know about oop... 
But i know mysqli, can be used as a function lib.. but youe right at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('" + $_POST['course'] + "')");
```

The method of string concatenation you are using is not supported in PHP. It is supported in other languages. There are multiple options to building your string.

Option 1: replace `+` with `.`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('".$_POST['course']."')");
```

Option 2: no break

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) values ('{$_POST['course']}')");
```

You should read up on the basics when going between languages, especially in this case a search for "PHP String Concatenation" will give you what you need.

Also: Do not use MySQL_* for it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO